# how to concatenate two value into single variable and stored in mysql database using php

Tags: php

I have two values, country code and phone number .while inserting into mysql database, concatenate country code and phone number and stored in single phone number column.

Comment: So your question is what exactly?

Comment: So what is the question, do you know how to concatenate in PHP?

Comment: Hello! Be sure to ask your question (question mark and everything) in your question body. I usually think about it as if sending an email: enough information in the subject to sum up your question ("Concatenating and storing into database"), but with the meat and details in the body.

Comment: [Welcome to SO, don't forget to **take the SO Tour** it will guide you on how to best use this site](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: Ok, stored phone. Now what?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- Concatenate the values into a variable with PHP and then insert this variable into de DB
- Use the MYSQL function concat: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do something like this ?

```
$value = $contryCode . $phone;
$sql   = 'INSERT INTO myTable contryCodeTelephone VALUES (' . $value . ')';
```

Comment: Would've been a better answer if it had used a prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

Lets day country code is in $ccode and phone number is in $phoneNum variable

Now use the following code :

```
$finalPhoneNumber = $ccode.$phoneNum // . is concatenation operator
```

Now you can use the $finalPhoneNumber as you want